# Как правильно организовать работу с классом (сохранение, поиск, и т.п.)?

Tags: ооп

Допустим есть класс `Car`, у данного класса есть какие-то свойства (цвет, модель, марка и т.д.) и методы (ехать). К данному классу я добавляю метод `save`, для того чтобы записать данную машину в базу. Насколько я понимаю, данный подход не совсем правильный, т.е. у данного класса, не должно быть методов не относящихся к нему.

Вопрос: как правильно добавить вспомогательный класс, чтобы в нем я могу указать все необходимые методы (`save`, `get`, `find`, `remove` и т.д)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае `Save` вполне себе относится к классу. Кто кроме как сам класс может знать о том какие, например, приватные поля он должен сохранить (сериализовать) и в каком виде.

Если же вы используете, к примеру, атрибуты полей и общую сериализацию, тогда `Save` может быть и не нужен. Вы создаете сериализатор и обрабатываете им переданный класс/объект согласно атрибутам (все сохраняемые поля - соответственно уже не приватные).

`Get`, `find`, `remove` - это скорее методы коллекции экземпляров класса.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass extends Car {

public function save() {}
public function get() {}
public function find() {}
public function remove() {}

и т.д.
}
```